# Wordpress Fatal Error - Yoast SEO plugin activation

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I'm trying to activate Yoast SEO plugin but I keep getting this error. Does anybody know what this means and how to fix it?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function register_block_type() in /homepages/14/d794412015/htdocs/behzad/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/src/integrations/blocks/structured-data-blocks.php:80 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/14/d794412015/htdocs/behzad/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/src/integrations/blocks/structured-data-blocks.php(71): Yoast\WP\SEO\Integrations\Blocks\Structured_Data_Blocks->register_blocks() #1 /homepages/14/d794412015/htdocs/behzad/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/src/loader.php(201): Yoast\WP\SEO\Integrations\Blocks\Structured_Data_Blocks->register_hooks() #2 /homepages/14/d794412015/htdocs/behzad/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/src/loader.php(137): Yoast\WP\SEO\Loader->load_integrations() #3 /homepages/14/d794412015/htdocs/behzad/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/lib/abstract-main.php(43): Yoast\WP\SEO\Loader->load() #4 /homepages/14/d794412015/htdocs/behzad/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/src/functions.php(36): Yoast\WP\Lib\Abstract_Main->load() #5 /homepages/14/d794412015/htdocs/behzad in /homepages/14/d794412015/htdocs/behzad/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/src/integrations/blocks/structured-data-blocks.php on line 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5T_xLB3els as guidance to solve your error.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.